# How to export Pandas data frame to excel and transpose with style defined in a column

Tags: excel, pandas, styles

My input looks like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NpU6V.png)

STYLE is a column i added in my program to specify format for each corresponding METRIC field.  We could change it to other content if my wording is not correct.  But the bottom line is that STYLE column defines the format for the corresponding METRIC column in the output excel file.

I want my output excel file to look like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76nIa.png)

As you can see, i want the output to be transposed with Date info moved to column header.  Unit is the index column, table content is METRIC, each METRIC is using the format specified in the STYLE column.  i want to export the content to an excel file.

I was able to export to the above excel file without the format.  But now i want to add the STYLE and i just cannot achieve that.  i have been playing with style.set_properties, style.apply with no success.

Thank you.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Data (Notice lightgreen instead of light green and semi colon seperator between background-color and color):

```
import pandas as pd


data = {
    "WEEKLY_FIRSTDAY": ["1/21/2023", "1/21/2023", "1/21/2023", "1/21/2023",
                        "1/28/2023", "1/28/2023", "1/28/2023", "1/28/2023"],
    "WEEKLY_LASTDAY": ["1/27/2023", "1/27/2023", "1/27/2023", "1/27/2023",
                       "2/3/2023", "2/3/2023", "2/3/2023", "2/3/2023"],
    "UNIT": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D"],
    "METRIC": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
    "STYLE": ["background-color: green", "background-color: lightgreen", "background-color: yellow",
              "background-color: yellow; color: red", "background-color: lightgreen; color: red",
              "background-color: lightgreen", "background-color: yellow",
              "background-color: yellow; color: red"]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

Create headers column from concatenated dates:

```
df["HEADERS"] = df.pop("WEEKLY_FIRSTDAY").str.cat(df.pop("WEEKLY_LASTDAY"), sep="_")
```

Create dictionary that maps css to value in specific column:

```
color_mapping = {k: v.groupby("METRIC")["STYLE"].apply(list).to_dict() for k, v in df.groupby("HEADERS")}
```

Pivot the df to desired format:

```
df = df.pivot(index="UNIT", columns="HEADERS", values="METRIC").reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Create functions to add color:

```
def color_column_1(val) -> dict:
    return {k: v[0] for k, v in color_mapping.get(df.columns[1]).items()}.get(val)


def color_column_2(val) -> dict:
    return {k: v[0] for k, v in color_mapping.get(df.columns[2]).items()}.get(val)
```

Call styler and write to Excel:

```
(df
 .style
 .applymap(color_column_1, subset=df.columns[1])
 .applymap(color_column_2, subset=df.columns[2])
 ).to_excel("/path/to/output/final.xlsx", index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the above reply, which gives me an idea to re-evaluate my problem and came up with another solution.

My original problem is actually two problems rolled into one: first is to preprocess data to a certain format. My specific pre-processing is to concatenate two columns WEEKLY_FIRSTDAY and WEEKLY_LASTDAY and then transpose (pivot) it. The second set of problem is to export the pre-processed data using pre-defined style into an excel file. The two problems can be separated. It is the second export with style to excel that bothers me. From solution above, i am able to get a universal solution to this export problem.

3 steps to export data to excel with pre-defined style:

1. get data into the right export format, without style.
2. create the style data frame, with exactly the same data structure, but the content is all style strings.
3. use apply function to export to excel with desired format

I put the complete code below for your reference:

```
# below code create input, this is specific to my data:
import pandas as pd 
data = { "WEEKLY_FIRSTDAY": ["1/21/2023", "1/21/2023", "1/21/2023", "1/21/2023", "1/28/2023", "1/28/2023", "1/28/2023", "1/28/2023"], "WEEKLY_LASTDAY": ["1/27/2023", "1/27/2023", "1/27/2023", "1/27/2023", "2/3/2023", "2/3/2023", "2/3/2023", "2/3/2023"], "UNIT": ["A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D"], "METRIC": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], "STYLE": ["background-color: green", "background-color: lightgreen", "background-color: yellow", "background-color: yellow; color: red", "background-color: lightgreen; color: red", "background-color: lightgreen", "background-color: yellow", "background-color: yellow; color: red"] } 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=data)

# concatenate WEEKLY_FIRSTDAY and WEEKLY_LASTDAY, create HEADERS column, again, this is specific for my data
df["HEADERS"] = df.pop("WEEKLY_FIRSTDAY").str.cat(df.pop("WEEKLY_LASTDAY"), sep="_")

# export step 1: get data into desired output format, without style:
# pivot on metric:
df_metric = df.drop(['STYLE'], axis=1)
df_metric = df_metric.pivot(index="UNIT", columns="HEADERS", values="METRIC").reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
print(df_metric)

  UNIT  1/21/2023_1/27/2023  1/28/2023_2/3/2023
0    A                    1                   5
1    B                    2                   6
2    C                    3                   7
3    D                    4                   8

# export step 2: create the style data frame, with exactly the same data structure, but the content is all style strings.:
df_style = df.drop(['METRIC'], axis=1)
df_style = df_style.pivot(index="UNIT", columns="HEADERS", values="STYLE").reset_index().rename_axis(None, axis=1)
df_style.loc[:,'UNIT'] = 'background-color: none'
print(df_style)

                     UNIT  ...                        1/28/2023_2/3/2023
0  background-color: none  ...  background-color: lightgreen; color: red
1  background-color: none  ...              background-color: lightgreen
2  background-color: none  ...                  background-color: yellow
3  background-color: none  ...      background-color: yellow; color: red

# export step 3: use apply function to export to excel with desired format

def highlight_cols(x, arg):
    df = arg
    return df   
 
df_metric.style.apply(highlight_cols, arg = df_style, axis=None).to_excel('./temp/output_style.xlsx', sheet_name='formatted', index=False)
```

[excel output looks like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNbqw.png)